# try to run below robot framework code

Tags: robotframework

```
Update testrail status
        Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='PASS'    '${result}=    run process    python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase.py'
        ELSE IF    '${result}=    run process    python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase1.py'
```

getting below error:

> 'Else If' is a reserved keyword. It must be in uppercase (ELSE IF)
>   when used as a marker with 'Run Keyword If'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ELSE IF` as a standalone keyword. If you want it to be part of your `Run Keyword If` statement, you need to make it all one statement. The easiest way is to use robot's method of line continuations:

```
Update testrail status
        Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='PASS'    '${result}=    run process    python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase.py'
        ...  ELSE IF      '${result}=   run process    python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase1.py'
```

However, this still won't work because `Run keyword if` requires a keyword as its second argument, not a variable. You can't simply use single quotes to make robot think it's a complete statement.

You have to capture the result of `Run keyword if`, rather than capturing it the way you are doing. You can make the code a bit more readable if you break it into multiple lines:

```
${result}=  run keyword if   '${status}' == 'PASS'  
...  run process  python  python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase.py'
...  ELSE IF  '${status}' == 'FAIL'
...  run process  python  python    \\Python27\\Scripts\\Impact_CM_Python_Automation\\PostCase1.py'
```

Comment: Still, I am getting below error. Please help me.

'Else If' is a reserved keyword. It must be in uppercase (ELSE IF) when used as a marker with 'Run Keyword If'.